# java.net.SocketException in SOAP call

Tags: java, exception, soap

I'm looking for an expert's input on this problem.

I have a java application that connects with remote system via SOAP API. We have this same application (client) running across multiple laptops and hitting various environments (dev, test and production) as required. All is fine except in one laptop in which requests to production (only) fail intermittently. The exception I'm getting is given below:

```
Mar 14, 2013 10:53:31 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Connection reset
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:466)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
    at $Proxy49.fareMasterPricerTravelBoardSearch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ace.amadeus.service.impl.MasterPriceSearchServiceImpl.fareMasterTravelBoardSearch(MasterPriceSearchServiceImpl.java:309)
    at com.ace.amadeus.controller.MasterPricerController.onSubmit(MasterPricerController.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection reset
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:93)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:861)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1273)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1836)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1794)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:96)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
    ... 36 more

javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:145)
    at $Proxy49.fareMasterPricerTravelBoardSearch(Unknown Source)
    at com.ace.amadeus.service.impl.MasterPriceSearchServiceImpl.fareMasterTravelBoardSearch(MasterPriceSearchServiceImpl.java:309)
    at com.ace.amadeus.controller.MasterPricerController.onSubmit(MasterPricerController.java:321)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Connection reset
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:220)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:466)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:251)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection reset
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:313)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:93)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:861)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1262)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1289)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1273)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:523)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1087)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1836)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1794)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:42)
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Writer.flush(UTF8Writer.java:96)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BufferingXmlWriter.flush(BufferingXmlWriter.java:214)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sw.BaseStreamWriter.flush(BaseStreamWriter.java:311)
    ... 36 more
```

Do you have any idea what might have happened? To remind you, this happens in only one of many laptops running the same code and config, only in production environment (It's working great in all other environments. There never is any problem), and only at times.

One more thing: if I make calls using SOAPUI from the same laptop, there's no exception.

Your time and response is very appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Additionally, there's one message that keeps popping on this particular laptop only (in eclipse log). I'm not sure this could be a reason though:

```
Mar 14, 2013 12:19:30 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
WARNING: Request method 'HEAD' not supported
```

Comment: the log shows `Connection reset`. Did you check your connection yet ?

Comment: yes, it's not because of internet connection for sure.

Comment: did you try telnet to the port ? Okay to view in browser does not mean your connection is successful.

Comment: As I mentioned, when I make a SOAP request with SOAPUI, the request is always successful.

Comment: I've added one more information in **EDIT**. That might give some clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds unlikely, but it was because of JDK version. We downgraded JDK version from 1.7 to 1.6 and it worked flawlessly.

Turns out, we banged our head for a whole month to later find out it was version incompatibility :o

Comment: In my case it was the server that switched from using JDK 1.6 to 1.7 and then the client started throwing errors.  Thanks to you banging your head for a month I only had to bang my head for six hours.

Comment: honestly a whole month?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given, the root error is:

> Request method 'HEAD' not supported

You can tell your controller to support the `HEAD` method using `setSupportedMethods(String[] supportedMethodsArray)`.

Reference: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?11794-Request-method-HEAD-not-supported-how-to-avoid-this-error

Comment: Actually our application nowhere makes a HEAD request explicitly. I wonder where this came from. The thing is, this doesn't display in other laptops with the same code and database.

Comment: Defining HEAD support on server side is also not an option because we're developing only the client side application.